# Apache CXF interceptors not triggered in WebLogic 12c?

Tags: apache, cxf, interceptor, weblogic12c

Please, I am stuck for many days having always the same error. I am testing the helloWorld apache cxf example where I added an interceptor to get information from the HTTP header.

I am developing using IDEA Intellij 11.0.2 and it works wonderfully when I test it inside Intellij but when I deploy the artifact in WebLogic 12c I have always a null pointer exception.

I am having the same error in a local WebLogic 12c in my personal computer (Windows 7 Professional) and also in WebLogic 12c in a UNIX server AIX 7.1.

I use JDK 1.7.0 plus Apache CXF 2.7.12.

When I debug the code in IDEA Intellij, I see that the interceptor constructor is executed and the handleMessage too, so everything works fine. But when debugging in WebLogic, the constructor is executed but the handleMessage is never executed.

My problem is in this line of code:

```
    Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
```

Variable "message" is correctly populated when I execute/debug in IDEA Intellij but it is always NULL when I execute/debug in WebLogic. Anyway, I think the problem is happening before becuase as I wrote, "handleMessage" is never invoked in WebLogic but in IDEA Intellij is.

I add some screenshots of the debugging in IDEA Intellij and WebLogic to show you what I mean. I changed the line:

```
    Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
```

For these 3 lines because I saw I have the same results but more things to show you when debugging:

```
    Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus(); 
    PhaseInterceptorChain chain = new PhaseInterceptorChain(bus.getExtension(PhaseManager.class).getInPhases()); 
    Message message = chain.getCurrentMessage();
```

This is what I get when debugging in Intellij (everything works fine):

--> sorry, I can't post images until having at least 10 reputation. Anyway, here I show that the interceptor was added programmatically and in runtime, constructor and handleMessage in interceptor are executed so everything works fine. "bus", "chain" and "message" are correctly populated.

And this is what I get when debugging in WebLogic (not working as I expected):

--> sorry, I can't post images until having at least 10 reputation. Anyway, here I show that the interceptor was added programmatically and in runtime, constructor in interceptor is executed but handleMessage in interceptor is never executed so finally I have an error because "bus", "chain" are populated but "message" is null.

Finally, some code:

1) HelloWorldImpl.java

```
package example; 

import org.apache.cxf.Bus; 
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory; 

import javax.jws.WebMethod; 
import javax.jws.WebService; 

import org.apache.cxf.message.Message; 
import org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain; 
import org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager; 

@WebService() 
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld { 

    public HelloWorldImpl() { 
        Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus(); 
        UserCredentialInterceptor myInterceptor = new UserCredentialInterceptor(); 
        bus.getInInterceptors().add(myInterceptor); 
    } 

    @WebMethod 
    public String sayHelloWorldFrom(String from) { 
        //Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage(); 
        Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus(); 
        PhaseInterceptorChain chain = new PhaseInterceptorChain(bus.getExtension(PhaseManager.class).getInPhases()); 
        Message message = chain.getCurrentMessage(); 
        if (message==null) { 
            System.out.println("HELLOWORLD ERROR"); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("HELLOWORLD OK"); 
        } 

        String result = "Hello, world, from " + from; 
        System.out.println(result); 
        return result; 
    } 
}
```

2) UserCredentialInterceptor.java

```
package example; 

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage; 
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor; 
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor; 
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault; 
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase; 
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination; 
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException; 
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader; 
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage; 
import java.util.Enumeration; 
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie; 

public class UserCredentialInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor { 
    private SAAJInInterceptor saajIn = new SAAJInInterceptor(); 

    public UserCredentialInterceptor() { 
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL); 
        getAfter().add(SAAJInInterceptor.class.getName()); 
    } 

    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault { 
        SOAPMessage doc = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class); 
        if (doc == null) { 
            saajIn.handleMessage(message); 
            doc = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class); 
        } 
        SOAPHeader headerr = null; 
        try { 
            headerr = doc.getSOAPHeader(); 
        } catch (SOAPException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        if (headerr != null) { 
            NodeList nodes = headerr.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://asjava.com/types", "Username"); 
            if (nodes != null && nodes.item(0) != null) { 
                String user = nodes.item(0).getTextContent(); 
            } 
        } 
        //if you want to read more http header messages, just use get method to obtain from  HttpServletRequest. 
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST); 
        if(null!=request){ 
            //Read http header to get client IP adress 
            String addr = request.getRemoteAddr(); 
            //Read http header to get HeaderNames 
            Enumeration enums = request.getHeaderNames(); 
            //Read http header to get cookie/ 
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

3) application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC 
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN" 
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd"><application>
    <display-name>test_interceptors</display-name>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>/</web-uri>
            <context-root>/</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

4) weblogic-application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.wsdl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

5) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

    <description>cxf</description>

    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

6) weblogic.xml

```
<weblogic-web-app 
        xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

7) cxf-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
      xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
      xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
      xsi:schemaLocation=" 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
</beans>
```

Please, any help is very appreciated.

thanks 
Felix Mercader.

Comment: Thats a huge code block. Try to read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)first. It is quite hard to read through all those (mostly unneccessary) code lines

Comment: I would like to add two images because they show all the differences I have when debugging in Intellij or in WebLogic. But I can't because I don't have at least 10 reputation. Anyway, my problem is in line     Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage(); 
"message" is correctly populated in Intellij but null in WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

Your cxf-servlet.xml doesn't define any beans at all.   Thus, I'm guess that the Weblogic JAX-WS implementation is triggering and deploying the service and CXF isn't even being used.   Do a Thread.dumpStack in the service to see what implementation is being picked up.   I'm willing to bet there are not any org.apache.cxf things in there.

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much for your help. Yes, I know, my cxf-servlet.xml is not defining any beans. But I also tried adding in cxf-servlet.xml a the following bean:         <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="userCredentialInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>

    <bean id="userCredentialInterceptor" class="example.UserCredentialInterceptor>
    </bean> and the final result is the same: interceptor's constructor executed but never the handleMessage. Of course this problem again, in WebLogic because in Intellij works nicely.

Comment: I am going to try now Thread.dumpStack() in WebLogic and I will tell you what I see. At the moment I can confirm that in Intellij I see a lot of references to cfx. For instance:  at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)

Comment: Daniel ! Thank you so much ! Yes, Thread.dumpStack in WebLogic shows totally different things. No references to cxf, only to jaxws, so you were totally right. Now I am going to put my bean back in cxf-servlet.xml but I am sure this will not fix the problem. I am quite sure that Thread.dumpStack() will still not show any cxf stuff. Anyway, this is an excellent lead ! Thanks again !

Comment: Daniel... I am following the instructions here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-WebLogic to deploy Apache CXF in WebLogic but no way. It does not work. Always using jaxws instead of cxf. Anyway, in that link it says it is validated on WebLogic 9.2 and I am using WebLogic 12c. Any advice ? Thanks

Comment: I opened a new topic here now that I see that the problem is not the interceptors but CXF that it is not being used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038187/why-apache-cxf-not-being-used-in-weblogic-12c